# How can I create cookies and also redirect to homepage of this app?

Tags: javascript, node.js

I got data from MySQL to check if my login is correct, so I need to save some data as cookies for 30 minutes and some redirect to my homepage. I tried to do so in a final code but, didn't work.

And to sane another curiosity: may I call a node.js code file (file that links to database e execute queries) in html file as script then use the ResultSet to fill the html form with JQuery?

```
// This one is what is in the top of modelAutonomo.js
var dadosJSON = JSON.stringify("{}");
const sql = require('../config/sql');
const requisicao = require('request');
var cookieNome = '';
var cookieEmail = '';
var cookieCPF = '';

var autonomo = {

...
...

// This is the function to login
fazerLogin: async function (entradaJSON) {
    var aux;
    console.log("Encontrado " + entradaJSON);
    dadosJSON = converterParaObjetoJSON(entradaJSON);
    aux = await sql.consultarAutonomoCPFeEmail(dadosJSON);

    console.log("Aux: " + aux);

    aux = JSON.parse(aux);

    console.log(dadosJSON.senha + " e " + aux.senha);

    if(dadosJSON.senha != aux.senha) {
      console.log("Senha incorreta!");

    } else if (dadosJSON.cpf != aux.cpf) {
      console.log("CPF incorreto!");

    } else {
      preencher(aux);
      console.log("Logado: " + autonomo.nome);

      cookieEmail = autonomo.email;
      cookieNome = autonomo.nome;
      cookieCPF = autonomo.cpf;

    }

    // I tried this to make the redirect, but don't even write the page html code in the console
    requisicao(__dirname + '/../html/index.html', function (error, response, body) {
      if (!error && response.statusCode == 200) {
        console.log(body) // Print the my web homepage.
      }
    });

  }
}
```

The structure of app is:

```
index.js
|--model
   |--modelAutonomo.js
|--config
   |--routes.js (who redirects to another pages/files of code)
|--html
   |--index.html (can be redirected by sending a request to "/")
|--controller
```

And this is the git repository of him:

https://github.com/diegossilva-1995-01-25/ReformaAqui

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I see in your repo that you are using express.js.  The express documentation is fairly straightforward:

- [set a cookie](http://expressjs.com/en/4x/api.html#res.cookie)
- [redirect](http://expressjs.com/en/4x/api.html#res.redirect)

```
res.cookie(cookieName, cookieValue);
res.redirect(redirectPath);
```

That `res` variable is available in the request handler.

Comment: I am really glad you answered, gentleman. So, which method I should use to put this inside, because o app.use(path, callback (req, res) { // create cookies and redirect }); seems not to work, it's like the code can't see this method or the callback.

Comment: As I already have promises and async/await, I made data make all the way back from models to routes.js using return with await in async functions, so worked. I thank ya for the good will on helping me out.